# Using HTML5 compliant tables in CkEditor

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, ckeditor

I noticed that by using the default table plug-in of CkEditor (see [this](http://ckeditor.com/addon/table) and [this](http://ckeditor.com/addon/tabletools)), you can add a table to your editor.

My problem, now, is that I need to force the editor content (got with `editor.getData()`) to be **HTML5 valid**.

In fact, when I add a table, the result is like the following:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1" style="width: 500px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            [...]
        </td>

        [...]

    </tr>

    [...]

</table>
```

As you can see, there are some attributes of the `table` tag that are [deprecated in HTML5](http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=545). In the above example, you can see `cellspacing`, `border` and `cellspadding`.

Someone reported this problem at dev.ckeditor.com (see [this](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10688) and [this other](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10021) tickets), but there is no explanation about the solution of this problem.

Do you know some tricks to solve this issue?

---

### My Solution

I want to share my solution, based on the [Reinmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1464696/reinmar) answer.

I added in the `config.js` file the following line:

```
config.disallowedContent = "table[cellspacing,cellpadding,border,align,summary,bgcolor,frame,rules,width]; td[axis,abbr,scope,align,bgcolor,char,charoff,height,nowrap,valign,width]; th[axis,abbr,align,bgcolor,char,charoff,height,nowrap,valign,width]; tbody[align,char,charoff,valign]; tfoot[align,char,charoff,valign]; thead[align,char,charoff,valign]; tr[align,bgcolor,char,charoff,valign]; col[align,char,charoff,valign,width]; colgroup[align,char,charoff,valign,width]";
```

In this way, I disabled every [non-HTML5 attributes](http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=545), related to tables.

Comment: So is your question about how to configure ACF?

Comment: I don't know how ACF can solve my problem. If you know a way to use it to help me, it can be a valid solution.

Comment: I haven't personally used ACF but it is the suggested method [here](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10021#comment:10) to do what you want. From a quick look I think you want [Disallowed Content](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content) specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since CKEditor 4.4 you can do this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    disallowedContent: 'table[cellspacing,cellpadding,border]'
} );
```

And voila :)!

You can read more in the [Disallowed Content](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content) guide.

Comment: I'm using CKEditor 4.3.1. Is there a safe way to upgrade to 4.4, without losing configurations and installed plugins?

Comment: It depends on what and how you installed and what have you changed. If you used [online builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder) you can upload the `build-config.js` which you can find the main directory. Then, backup your `config.js`, extract new version, replace config and there's a great chance that it will work. Make also sure that you read at least the important news from the [changelog](http://ckeditor.com/whatsnew).

Comment: I added my solution, using every attribute deprecated in HTML5, related to tables. Thank you again